# Run functions stored in a list based on criteria

Tags: r

I have a list of functions, for example:

```
    myFunctions = list(
         calculateMean = function(x) {mean(x)},
         calculateMedian = function(x) {median(x)}
         )
```

I need to call stored `functions` in `myFunctions` based on some criteria for example, I have a table (`myTable`) with prices and I need to calculate means and medians (I also need to do more things like standardize names, join a specific value with a table with codes, etc).

If a value in a column in `myTable` is `== "a"` I want to use function `calculateMean`, if `== "b"` I want to use function `calculateMedian`, if `== "c"` use function `calculateMean`.

What is the best way to do this? I am saving functions as a list as I will have a lot of functions. And how can I call a function in the `myFunctions` based on a specific criteria?

Thanks!

Comment: `myFunctions[[1]](c(1:10))`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"If a value in a column in myTable is == "a" I want to use function calculateMean"*,  it's mean of that row? And your data structure? Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(myTable)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(myTable, 20))`.

Comment: Also, instead of a list of functions, you could write your own custom function that would return mean, meadian, or whatever, depending on some additional arugment.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, in these datasets I have a column with IDs and a column with the prices. If the ID is equals, for example, "pears" I want to calculate the mean for column prices. If the ID is oranges I want to calculate the median. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following does what the question asks for.

Depending on `ID`, function `priceStat` determines which function from `myFunctions` to apply to column `price`.

```
priceStat <- function(x, funlist) {
  type <- unique(as.character(x[["ID"]]))
  f <- switch(type,
              pear = funlist[[1]],
              orange = funlist[[2]])
  f(x[["price"]])
}

myFunctions = list(
  calculateMean = function(x) {mean(x)},
  calculateMedian = function(x) {median(x)}
)

set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = sample(c("pear", "orange"), 20, TRUE),
                  price = runif(20),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sapply(split(df1, df1$ID), priceStat, myFunctions)
#   orange      pear 
#0.3036828 0.5427695
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I think does what you are suggesting.

```r
library(dplyr)
```

Create some data.

```r
set.seed(1234)
data <- tibble(id = rep(letters[1:2], each = 3), price = rnorm(6, 100, 5))
data

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   id    price
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a      94.0
# 2 a     101. 
# 3 a     105. 
# 4 b      88.3
# 5 b     102. 
# 6 b     103.
```

Create a list of functions. Note we named the list item for the `id` we want to apply it to.

```r
myFunctions <- list(
  a = mean,
  b = median
)
```

Group the data on the `id`. Then iterate over each list item, calling `summarize()`. For each list (which is the subset of the data for that given `id`) call the function from the `myFunctions` list.

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ summarize(.x, calc = myFunctions[[pull(.y[1])]](.x$price)))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   id     calc
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a      100.
# 2 b      102.
```

Testing it out.

```r
> mean(data$price[data$id == "a"])
[1] 100.258
> median(data$price[data$id == "b"])
[1] 102.1456
```